# Possible bug in move_base.launch

Tags: navigation, mapping, move-base, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
For several days, I (a relative newbie) have been trying to get the nav stack working.  My map always came up offset from the robot in rviz (origin at lower left corner of map).

I finally found that the move_base.launch file in the "Setup and Configuration of the Navigation Stack on a Robot" tutorial (para. 3.5) is using a deprecated version of map_server arguments (as noted in the map_server code).  It uses the "map_server  " form rather than the "map_server <map.yaml>" form.  The deprecated version doesn't work properly  and the associated ROS_WARN message that map_server apparently should be displaying didn't show up on my terminal.

I suggest that the launch file be updated.  This was pretty hard to track down.

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9878/possible-bug-in-move_base.launch/) by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file this as a ticket using the appropriate trac. There's a link on the [navigation wiki page.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0